# Updating GridView row in edit mode from text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to replace "_" character from my TextBox which is wraped with MaskedEditExtender to validate data entry when editing TextBox.

```
            <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="TextBox1_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server"
                CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder=""
                CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder=""
                CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True"
                InputDirection="RightToLeft" Mask="9999.9" MaskType="Number"
                TargetControlID="TextBox1" ClearTextOnInvalid="False>
            </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
```

When I try to edit row. Textbox value is "__12.4" . In GridView1_RowUpdating I am trying to replace "_" with "" with no results.

```
        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox Textbox1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Textbox1 ");
        Label Label2 = new Label();
        Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("_", "");
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

My TemplateField looks like this

```
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Decimal Value" SortExpression="DecimalValue">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DecimalValue","{0:F1}") %>' Height="20px" MaxLength="6" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
            <%-- Formated to display 9999.9 per requirement --%>
            <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="TextBox1_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server"
                CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder=""
                CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder=""
                CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True"
                InputDirection="RightToLeft" Mask="9999.9" MaskType="Number"
                TargetControlID="TextBox1" ClearTextOnInvalid="False">
            </asp:MaskedEditExtender>

        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DecimalValue", "{0:F1}") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I don't know where to update TextBox1.text value after row is update and send this to MS SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is when you select the row, becouse you select the row, take the textbox but never change the value:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    TextBox Textbox1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Textbox1 ");
    Label Label2 = new Label();
    Label2.Text = GridView1.Text.Replace("_", "");
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I think is (see code below)

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    TextBox Textbox1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Textbox1 ");
    Label Label2 = new Label();
    Label2.Text = Textbox1.Text.Replace("_", ""); //Replace Gridview for the text box
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

But here only you'll replace the Character and put in a Label, it won't be update the texbox.

Cheer

Comment: @Framk_Droid Thanks, I edit misspelled control. I am not sure how I can reach this textbox after row is updated and check what is in the Text property. It's throwing the error string is not in correct format after updated it have to be without "_" character then it will be OK

Comment: The erros maybe is, becouse you need do  `double.Parse(Textbox1.Text.Replace("_", "").ToString());` Why? becouse you are try to put a string whitout cast to a double field. I guess that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to databind your gridview in rowupdating if you have a datasource handling updates for you, can you try this and see what happens?

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox Textbox1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Textbox1");
    Textbox1.Text = Regex.Replace(Textbox1.Text, "_", "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.This solution is replacing "_" character when I debug but I got error after row is updated about string not being in correct format. How I could see Text property value after updated event.

Comment: which string is not in correct format? can you post the error more detailed?